# Will clothes be impure due to pre-cum

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-basis

If a couple had foreplay and nothing happened, the male had some sticky dripping on the pajamas (not sperm) , will he need to have ghusal?

Here I am talking about anything of foreplay or touching but not having a intercouse yet there is some sticky dripping/dots on clothes. Will clothes become impure and so does person and ghusal in needed?

Comment: This has been answered on the site before. Madhiy is impure and needs to be washed from whatever it touches including your private parts and clothes, however it does not require ghusl, rather you must do wudu.

Answer (score -1):

Good question and the short answer it is better if you perform ghusal. If you are not able to then wash the area. Here is a more detailed scholarly explanation. https://seekersguidance.org/answers/hanafi-fiqh/ghusl-ritual-bath-urine/